# merging data frames with empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=["x"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1],"a":[3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1],"b":[6]})
```

I'd like to merge the `df1` with `empty`.

```
    x  a 
0   1  3
```

I tried

```
empty.merge(df1, on=["x"])
```

but this returns an empty data frame. After successfully merging with `df1`, I'd like to be able to merge `empty` again with `df2` so that it results in

```
    x  a  b 
0   1  3  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify 'how' in a merge function it defaults to an 'inner' join which HAS to match keys on both sides of the merge. If you change it to a 'left' or 'right' join when you merge it will preserve the data:

```
empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=["x"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1],"a":[3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1],"b":[6]})
df3 = empty.merge(df1, on=["x"],how='right').merge(df2,how='right')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is clear in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html): `merge` defaults to an inner join.  Since there are no keys in your left table, you get no keys in the result.  Fix this simply by specifying an outer join:

```
empty.merge(df1, how="inner", on=["x"])
```

Full demonstration:

```
>>> accum = empty.merge(df1, "outer")
>>> accum
   x  a
0  1  3
>>> accum = accum.merge(df2, "outer")
>>> accum
   x  a  b
0  1  3  6
>>>
```